# Insert HTML superscript tags into a text formula

Tags: python, string

From a file, I have got strings like:

```
4f^145d^66s^2
```

I have to format that with HTML `<sup>` tags:

```
4f<sup>14</sup>5d<sup>6</sup>6s<sup>2</sup>
```

So that it'll render as: 4f<sup>14</sup>5d<sup>6</sup>6s<sup>2</sup>

This is an example and I have to format hundreds of them, so, doing it manually is not possible.

What I have to do is replace `^` with `<sup>`(which is not problem); **find the next `[a-z]`, and insert `</sup>` one digit before that **(this is the problematic part), or at the end of the string.

How I can do that?

Comment: I don't know what digits are the part of the exponent. All I know, is that the format is:
[0-9][a-z][exponent][0-9][a-z][exponent]. I know that [0-9] has single digit, but exponent part may be 1 or 2 digit. 
That it why, I am trying to do what I said in the bold font. the **one digit before alpha** is important

Answer (score 0):

If *all digits except the last before a letter* are part of the exponent, then you can use a regular expression:

```
re.sub(r'\^(\d+)(?=\d[a-z]|$)', r'<sup>$1</sup>', formula)
```

This matches any number of digits after the `^` character, but won't include a last digit before a letter. `(?=...)` part is a *look-ahead expression*; it only matches to a position in the input where the next character is a digit followed by a letter, *or* the end of the string. This lets you match the `^14` in `^145d` without including the `5d`.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> formula = '4f^145d^66s^2'
>>> re.sub(r'\^(\d+)(?:\d[a-z]|$)', r'<sup>\1</sup>', formula)
'4f<sup>14</sup>5d<sup>6</sup>6s<sup>2</sup>'
```

You can also play with the expression and the substitutions in [this regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/WCulVg/1).